# Show that the function $M(x,y)=xy$ is continuous on any disk; $\mid (x,y) \mid \leq r$

Tags: continuity

I cant seem to prove this thing. By working on the definition:
a function f is continuous at $p_0 \in D$ if for every $\epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0$ such that $\mid f(p) - f(p_0)\mid < \epsilon$ whenever $\mid p-p_0 \mid < \delta$.

Well I tried working backwards. Let $p = (x,y)$ and $p_0 = (x_0 , y_0)$

- $\mid M(p) - M(p_0) \mid = \mid xy - x_0y_0 \mid = \mid (x-x_0)y + x_0(y-y_0) \mid < \epsilon$

If $\mid p - p_0 \mid < \delta$

$\Rightarrow \mid \delta y + \delta x_0\mid = \delta \mid y + x_0 \mid < \epsilon$

Now is it alright for me to choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{y + x_0}$?

I'm confused, what if $y+x_0 = 0$ at some point in the disk? or is this possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{eqnarray}
|x_1 y_1 - x_2 y_2| &\le& |x_1 y_1 - x_1 y_2| + | x_1 y_2- x_2 y_2| \\
&=& |x_1||y_1-y_2| + |y_2||x_1-x_2| \\
&\le& r (|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: you sir, are a genius!!! thanks so much for this!!

Comment: @llawliet_78: I wish :-). It is one of the standard tricks, worth remembering.

Comment: sorry I don't see why $|x_1| * + |y_2|** \leq r (* + **)  $, can you explain, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what particular step is causing you concern, we have $|x_1| \le r$ and $|y_2| \le r$.

Comment: @LilianHernández: Since $|x_1|\leq r$, we can multiply both sides of the inequality by $|y_1-y_2|$, getting that $|x_1||y_1-y_2| \leq r|y_1-y_2|$. 

Repeating the same process for $|y_2| \leq r$, we multiply both sides of the inequality by $|x_1-x_2|$ to get 

$|y_2||x_1-x_2| \leq r|x_1-x_2|$. We add both of the inequalities together to get 

$|x_1||y_1-y_2| + |y_2||x_1-x_2| \leq r|y_1-y_2| + r|x_1 -x_2|=r(|y_1-y_2|+|x_1-x_2|)$

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time, now It's way clearer.